# developerstory.dev: Re-home your Story, or download as JSON

Tags: app, website, stackoverflow

[image: Developer Story Dot Dev]

### About

Hi, I'm Jess Telford, I created [developerstory.dev](https://developerstory.dev/stackoverflow)

When I heard StackOverflow will be discontinuing their Developer Story feature[*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story), I couldn't just let my story get deleted! Being a developer myself, I put together a script to download it as JSON, and dutifully copied it to a USB drive for safe keeping.

But, what good is my story **sitting on a USB drive**?

So, I brewed a strong cuppa and got to work: I needed something that reflected the StackOverflow Timeline style, but with a modern take, and built for the mobile web. Something I would be proud to show my friends, family, and potential employers. Something that really *told my unique story*.

After 6 (very loooong) days, DeveloperStory.dev was born! I uploaded the JSON file, published it to the web, and finally have *a permanent home for my story* that wont get deleted at the whim of a big corporate. I'm pretty proud of how it turned out, wanna see? [Jess Telford's Developer Story](https://developerstory.dev/story/jesstelford).

---

And it doesn't end there! What about your story, dear reader? It deserves a permanent home of its own, too. Well, the good news is; I couldn't stop at just my story, so I built a **StackOverflow Developer Story Importer** for anyone to use, including you!

All you have to do is import the story from your StackOverflow account, then you have the option of either downloading it as JSON, or publishing it to its forever-home on DeveloperStory.dev. Give it a try:

**https://developerstory.dev/stackoverflow**

It's still early days (I'm honoured that you're among the first users of this site! ❤️), so if you run into any issues, or have any feedback, I would love to hear from you!

#### Pricing

Free!